# Stochastic calculus - Ito confusion

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-calculus

We have $W(t) = f(t)X(t)$. My textbook says that $dW = fdX + X\dfrac{df}{dt} dt$.

I don't get how they arrived at this conclusion. I get the first part, because $\dfrac{dW}{dX}dX = fdX$. But for the second part, I have no clue how they arrived there.

$(\dfrac{dW}{dt} + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d^2W}{dX^2})dt \stackrel{?}{=} X\dfrac{df}{dt} dt$

If so, could someone please explain why?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I can't seem to figure out how that would give the answer above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ito formula for a function $g(t, x)$ is
  $$d\bigl(g(t, X_t)\bigr) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t, X_t)\, dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t, X_t)\, dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} (t, X_t)\,d[X, X]_t$$
In your case, $W_t = g(t, X_t)$ for the function $g(t, x) = f(t)x$. The partials of $g$ are:
  $$\begin{split}
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t, x) &{}= f'(t)x,\\
    \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t, x) &{}= f(t),\\
    \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(t, x) &{} = 0.
  \end{split}$$
Substitution into the Ito formula gives your book's expression.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the notation $d[X,X]_t$, can you explain? And I assume those $(t,X_t)$ should have been placed next to the $g$'s?

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused here "In your case, $W_t = g(t,X_t)$ for the function $g(t,x) = f(t)x$. Why are $x$ and $X_t$ used here interchangeably? And how come $W_t$ is also a function of $X_t$ when in the book it's written as $W(t)$?

Comment: @Messi $x$ and $X_t$ are different: $x$ is a real number, $X_t$ is a random variable. $W_t$ (or $W(t)$ in your book's notation) is a random variable, the product of the deterministic value $f(t)$ with the random variable $X_t$.

Comment: @Messi Similarly $g(t, x)$ is a real-valued (deterministic) function of two variables, so it makes sense to take derivatives only on the level of $g(t, x)$. On the other hand $g(t, X_t)$ is the random variable whose value at an event $\omega$ is the real number $g(t, X_t(\omega))$.